# What are the main differences between a site collection and a collection of sub-sites?

Tags: 2013, site-collection, sub-site

I need to choose between making a bunch of sub-sites or site collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Site Collection in SharePoint is basically a collection of SharePoint sites that share common features like Content types, Templates, Site columns, permissions, Web Parts etc.

[image]

**Separate Site Collections**

1. Unique set of users and permissions
2. Unique and separated content databases are possible, which allow for multiple large (200GB+) sites
3. Unique set of workflows, site content types, site columns
4. Unique quotas
5. All farm services are shared
6. Upgrade to next version can be done in a phase approach
   Cons

**Single site collection with Sub Sites**

1. Easier data propagation and collaboration, share data and content from site to site
2. Shared permission management across all sites
3. Single content database makes backing up easier
4. True site hierarchy and navigation